# Unable to get blob from Azure Blob Storage in Angular 8

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 and trying to save and download Files from Azure Blob Storage. I have successfully implemented Save File (`uploadFile` works good) but running into issues trying to get file(`downloadFile()`) as the  `downloadResponse.readableStreamBody` is `undefined`.

Below is the code:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as AzureStorage from '@azure/storage-blob';
import {BlockBlobURL, ContainerURL} from '@azure/storage-blob';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AzureBlobService {
  containerURL: ContainerURL;

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
  }


  async uploadFile(CONNECT_STR: string, file: File) {
    this.containerURL = await new AzureStorage.ContainerURL(
      CONNECT_STR,
      AzureStorage.StorageURL.newPipeline(
        new AzureStorage.AnonymousCredential()
      )
    );
    const blockBlobUrl = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(this.containerURL, file.name);
    try {
      const upload = AzureStorage.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(
        AzureStorage.Aborter.none,
        file,
        blockBlobUrl
      );
      await upload;
      return Promise.resolve(upload);
    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    }
  }

  async downloadFile(CONNECT_STR: string, fileName: string) {
    const containerURL = await new AzureStorage.ContainerURL(
      CONNECT_STR,
      AzureStorage.StorageURL.newPipeline(
        new AzureStorage.AnonymousCredential()
      ));
    const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, fileName);
    const downloadResponse = await blockBlobURL.download(AzureStorage.Aborter.none, 0);
    return downloadResponse.readableStreamBody;
  }
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^10.3.0",
```

I have used this as reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries-v10

I appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me:

Code:

```
  async downloadFile(CONNECT_STR: string, fileName: string) {
    const containerURL = await new AzureStorage.ContainerURL(
      CONNECT_STR,
      AzureStorage.StorageURL.newPipeline(
        new AzureStorage.AnonymousCredential()
      ));
    const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, fileName);
    const downloadResponse = await blockBlobURL.download(AzureStorage.Aborter.none, 0);
    return downloadResponse.blobBody;
  }
```

I read the below documentation in the Azure code that helped
Comment:

> - In Node.js, data returns in a Readable stream readableStreamBody
> - In browsers, data returns in a promise blobBody